# Pandas pivot giving me lots of 'none' values

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have an unusual data set that is giving me trouble. It is just a txtfile like so, with lots of records in this format just repeating the same format down the page. I can't be more specific - it's a coding test for a role and I'm going to be honest and say I had help so I won't get it, but it's really bugging me!

BEGIN:foo
NUM:stringwithnumbers-10000098888
DTTIME:20181101Z (imagine a proper datestamp here)
START:20180111
DESCRIPTION:Doing things
END:fooend

my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

stuff = pd.read_csv('thing.ical', sep=':', header=None, index_col=None, skiprows=6)
stuff.columns = ['cols', 'vals']
stuff['index_col'] = stuff.index
stuff = stuff.pivot( index=None, columns='cols')
print(stuff.head())

        vals                                                                   \
cols   BEGIN           DTSTAMP DTSTART;VALUE=DATE   END               SUMMARY   
0     foo                 None               None  None                  None   
1       None              None               None  None                  None   
2       None  stringwithnumbers-10000098888  None  None                  None   
3       None              None           20180111  None                  None   
4       None              None               None  None          Doing things
```

This gives me lots of none values in my pivoted df, which I don't want. I'm quite new to pivots and I don't understand what's going on?

Comment: Do you have to use pandas? The file extension is a big hint.

Comment: I didn't know there was another way! I've never come across ical format before! Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: look at icalendar package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for `Counter` for new `indices`. Also is possible use parameter `names` in `read_csv`, so then is not necessary assign list later:

```
df = pd.read_csv('thing.ical', sep=":", names=['cols', 'vals'], skiprows=6)
print (df)


df = pd.pivot(index=df.groupby('cols').cumcount(),
              columns=df['cols'],
              values=df['vals'])
```